# Cannot install RADIS in windows environment

Tags: python-3.x, hdf5

I'm using Python 3.9. I needed to install the Python RADIS module. But the following error encounters. All other questions regarding this error when encountered installing different modules have been answered by showing other effective ways to install those modules.

I forked this [repository](https://github.com/radis/radis) and followed instructions exactly as said [here](https://radis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/developer.html). 
The error I encounter is as this.
[image]

Comment: Is your Python installation from an Anaconda distribution? Did you try to install RADIS with pip? If not, I would try the pip installer before forking the Git repository,

Comment: tried using pip command, same error encounters

Comment: Hello @chanuka-naveen-koswatta. Do you still have the error on latest versions (0.13.1) ? If so we'll have a look and fix it.